# Relationships in InfyOm Generator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have News and NewsCategories models which I have generated CRUD for using the relationship option.

I now need to generate a select list for the News model to select the NewsCategory it belongs to.

I know how to do this in the model but no idea how to do it using the repository pattern.

I can't see any examples in the docs so any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

NewsRepository

```
/**
     * Configure the Model
     **/
    public function model()
    {
        return News::class;
    }
```

News Model

```
/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     **/
    public function newsCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(NewsCategory::class);
    }
```

News Controller

```
/**
     * Show the form for creating a new News.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('news.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created News in storage.
     *
     * @param CreateNewsRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(CreateNewsRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $news = $this->newsRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success('News saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('news.index'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your repository extends [InfyOm\Generator\Common\BaseRepository](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/blob/develop/src/Common/BaseRepository.php). The repository should update the model relations by it self. Just pass the relation values alongside the other inputs with the correct keys.

However, for deleting and reading (let's call them actions), you will need to query your data.

You can do that using repository methods, scope queries, or criteria classes.
(and call those filters).

1. Repository Methods:

   ```
   // inside your controller
   // some repository filtering method
   $this->repository->whereHas('newsGroup', function($query){...});
   $this->repository->hidden(['field_to_hide']);
   ...
   // some action: delete, all or findWhere...
   $this->repository->delete();
   ```
2. Scope Queries are callbacks that apply some queries on the model eloquent and  return it.(unlike Eloquent scopes which accept and return Database\Eloquent\Builder)

   ```
   $this->repository->scopeQuery(
            function ($model){ return $model->where(...);
   });
   Or your 
   // some action: delete, update or findWhere...
   $this->repository->delete();
   ```
3. The Criteria Way: you will create a class responsible on querying. It is an overkill for the simple use-cases.

   ```
   // inside the controller
   $this->repository->pushCriteria(new NewsBelongingToCategory ($group_id));

    // App\Criteria\NewsBelongingToCategory.php
    class NewsBelongingToCategory implements CriteriaInterface {

       private $group_id;

       public function __construct($group_id){
          $this->group_id = $group_id;
        }

       public function apply($model, NewsRepositoryInterface $repository)
          {
                $group_id = $this->group_id;
                $model = $model->whereHas('newsCategory',
                      function ($query) use ($group_id){
                          $query->where('group_id', '=', $group_id);
                      });
                 return $model;
           }
    } 

   // in your controller

   $this->repository->delete();
   ```

   Note that some actions ignore specific filters. For example, `delete(id)` and `update($attributes, $id)` does not use criteria, in the other hand `lists($column, $key)` does not use scopes.